# Initializing vector inside constructor giving seg fault

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have a card class in which I initialize a vector:

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Card
{
    private:
        vector<int> CC;
        vector<int> iChance;
    public:
        Card();
        void draw_Card();
};

#endif
```

And in my .cpp file I have

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>  
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include "card.h"

using namespace std;

Card::Card()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    vector<bool> drawn(20);   
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        int numvalue = rand()%20 + 1;   
        if (drawn[numvalue - 1])
        {
            i--;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            drawn[numvalue - 1] = true;
            CC.push_back(numvalue);
            iChance.push_back(numvalue);    
        }
    }
    copy (CC.begin(), CC.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
}
```

It is segfaulting when I call the push_back function for CC, which means the vector CC is not being passed in correctly?

If i called the vectors not in the private area and directly inside the constructor it works. Sorry if this maybe a really simple fix, just started learning classes and vectors. Thank you for the help.

Edit: I am almost certain this is the problem. The value of CC and iChance are not getting past into the constructor, so when the program tries to set a value to the variables nothing exists and it seg faults.

Also I noticed that if i instead declared the CC and iChance variable in the cpp file and not the .h file the program would work.

I am just trying to figure out why and how I could fix this

Comment: Your code looks perfectly fine.

Comment: it segfaults unless I declare the vector <int> CC inside the constructor.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Runs fine [here](http://ideone.com/6qCO5O)

Comment: This is a long shot: I figure there's also another class (or main program) that actually uses this class. Did you make sure that all dependent source files are recompiled when you modify the class.h header?

Comment: i'm using terminal on my macbook

Comment: and i am not using this class in any other class besides main

Comment: What happens if you put the Card class definition into the main file, with no header,  then have a 1-line main() that just defines a object of type Card?  If you use the same main() as us, we can rule out more variables.

Comment: Probably not related to your issue, but I doubt you want to call `srand` every time you construct a `Card`.  Better to call it once at the beginning of your program.  If you happened to construct several cards in the same second they would all have the same random sequence.

Comment: @sj0h just tried it and same result. What compiler are you guys using?

Comment: Also `using namespace std` inside header is bad practice.